# Get style property of each children using loop

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to get background color of each child element.

```
var arr = [];
for(var c = 0; c < 5; c++){
    var temp = div.children[c].style.backgroundColor;
    arr[c] = temp;
}
```

I can't seem to understand why it's not working because when I used the code below, it worked

```
div.children[c].style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
```

Comment: First, use `arr.push`. Second, its difficult to visualise without your markup. Can you create a JSFiddle or a working snippet?

Comment: Thanks for fast response, here's the bin http://jsbin.com/jomalatila/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *The [**`Window.getComputedStyle()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method gives the values of all the **`CSS`** properties of an element after applying the active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.*
>
> *The [**`HTMLElement.style`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object that represents only the **`element's inline style attribute`**, ignoring any applied style rules.*

---

`HTMLElement.style` only works for `inline-css`, use [**`getComputedStyle(Element)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get all the `style` object associated with `Element`.

Note: I would use `Array#push` instead of assigning values at specified `index`.

```js
var arr = [];
for (var c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
  var temp = getComputedStyle(div.children[c]).backgroundColor;
  arr.push(temp);
}
```

Comment: @PhoxKiD – I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 2):

An alternate to avoid custom creating of array.

#### Array.map.call

```js
var div = document.getElementById("text");
var arr = Array.prototype.map.call(div.children, function(el) {
  return window.getComputedStyle(el).backgroundColor;
})
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<div ID="text">
  <span style="background-color:rgb(200,20,20)">1</span>
  <span style="background-color:rgb(250,150,150)">2</span>
  <span style="background-color:rgb(150,100,0)">2</span>
</div>
```